# Java 8 Lambdas, Best way to filter on child lists

Tags: java, lambda, steam, review

I would like to filter the parent list based on the condition in the sublist of the sublist.

The Parent is Event it contains a list of Band and the list of Band contains a list of Member.

I have to return a list of Event based on Member name

```
@Entity
public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "event")
    private Set<Band> bands;
```

```
@Entity
public class Band {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    private Set<Member> members;
{...}
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Member {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    String name;
}
{...}
```

Here is the method i implemented :

```
public List<Event> getFilteredEventsInJava(String query) {
  

    final List<Event> events = Optional.ofNullable(eventRepository.findAllBy()).orElseGet(Collections::emptyList).stream()
            .filter(e -> Optional.ofNullable(e.getBands()).orElseGet(Collections::emptySet).stream()
                    .filter(b ->  Optional.ofNullable(b.getMembers()).orElseGet(Collections::emptySet).stream().
                            filter(m -> m.getName().contains(query)).count()>0).count()>0)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return events;

}
```

My code is working but can you help me to improve it?

I need help to improve my code

Comment: Add a method to `Event` called `hasMember` that takes a member and returns `boolean`. Then you just have one `filter` at the top-level that calls this `hasMember` function. While Java lambdas and streaming functions can be a useful technique to shorten simple code and eliminate boilerplate, they are not the "new" way of doing things, and when you have three `filter` calls nested inside of each other, it's definitely time to refactor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rig of excessive misuse of `Optional.ofNullable()` you can do the following changes:

- Make our repository return an empty `List` instead of `null`.
- Initialize all fields of type `List`, `Set`, `Map`, etc. with an empty collection by default.

Both these suggestions illustrated with examples can be found in the classic book *"Effective Java"* by Joshua Bloch (*former Sun-employee, author of Collections framework and other Java language features*).

Also, you can change `filter().count() > 0` to [`anyMatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)), which easier to read semantically more suitable:

```
public List<Event> getFilteredEventsInJava(String query) {
    
    return eventRepository.findAllBy() // don't return null from your repository - return an empty List
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getBands().stream() // initilize brands property with empty Set by default
            .anyMatch(b ->  b.getMembers().stream() // initilize members property with empty Set by default
                .anyMatch(m -> m.getName().contains(query)) // change nested filter().count() to anyMatch()
            )
        )
        .toList(); // for Java 16+ or collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

Comment: This is a great improvement. Using anyMatch instead of filter+count>0 is a good idea thanks. The set is filled from the bdd it's a many to many relation (the annotation is missing)